# Sails js connection reverts to development when deployed on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

I have been trying to deploy my sails app on heroku using mongolab as my mongodb.

I have used the following connections, one for development and one for production:

```
    local_mongo : {
    adapter  : 'sails-mongo',
    host     : 'localhost',
    port     : 27017,
    database : "something"
},

  heroku_mongolab : {
     adapter   : "sails-mongo",
     url       : "mongodb://*****:******!@ds063160.mongolab.com:63160/something"
  }
```

I have also set my local.js file to use development environment and out that file on gitignore.

Finally on my development.js I do the following

```
module.exports = {
   models: {
       connection: 'local_mongo'
     }
};
```

on my production.js

```
module.exports = {

/***************************************************************************
 * Set the default database connection for models in the production        *
 * environment (see config/connections.js and config/models.js )           *
 ***************************************************************************/

models: {
   connection: 'heroku_mongolab'
}

/***************************************************************************
 * Set the port in the production environment to 80                        *
 ***************************************************************************/

//port: 80

/***************************************************************************
 * Set the log level in production environment to "silent"                 *
 ***************************************************************************/

//log: {
//   level: "silent"
//}

};
```

and on my package.json I changed the start script to node app.js --prod. When running locally everything works as expected, even when I run npm start, but when I deploy on heroku and look at the logs I see that it tries to connect to the localhost mongodb.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a Procfile. Create a file named "Procfile" in the root directory of your application, to explicitly declare what command should be executed to start your app. In your case, to define production environment, add this line :

`web: NODE_ENV=production node app.js`

Answer (score 0):

If you want Heroku to run your application in production environment, you have to set the environment variable as follows:

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. The only way I can get it to work is when I comment out the local connection. Then it works just fine but it seems a bit odd to do something like that when there is a whole functionality to achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: Actually `config/local.js` is by default included in the .gitignore file. The file is used for local environment settings. You should add your `heroku_mongolab` to `config/connections.js`. This means that your local connection `local_mongo` should not be there in Heroku.

Comment: I figured that out and fixed it, but shouldn't it work with multiple connections? Isn't that the whole purpose of development and production modes?

Comment: Actually it should. But I have insufficient data to figure it out. Do you have your code hosted somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a private repo

Comment: @YedhuKrishnan is right; the `local.js` file is intended for what its name implies: settings local to your specific system, i.e. a single computer.  It will always override all other settings, but that's usually not a problem since it's not version controlled so it doesn't get deployed to other environments or shared between developers.  If it's showing up on Heroku, then it's either been removed from your `.gitignore` or you're not deploying via git.

Comment: I am also having this problem.

When I run:
NODE_ENV=production nodemon app.js  on my LOCAL machine it starts up with production settings.

However if I set NODE_ENV=production on heroku, and I console.log out process.env.NODE_ENV in the heroku logs I see its production, however it still attempts to use local mongo connection...